# How to preserve new line formatting Python string

Tags: python, string, replace

I am taking a historical SQL query from a database that preserves the user's original formatting. A return string looks like so

```
-- query comment: ran on June 1. See JIRA-123 for context
SELECT field1, field2 \\n -- some comment about the table \\n FROM table \\n WHERE foo
```

I want to assign this as a string variable, so I can template it and re-send it out to the SQL engine again.

However, the new line separators (`\n`) can't be in there. I can replace these easily enough. My problem is that when I send the query back out again I have lost the original formatting. This causes the query to fail when there are comments (indicated by `--`) in the original query, because they are not given their own lines they have the effect of commenting out **everything** after them.

In my example case this would would mean the whole query would be ready by the SQL engine as a comment and so not return anything.

All results I've seen online seem to deal exclusively with printing a multiline string, but I want to use it as an argument to another function where the new lines are read as new lines and not as a string representation of `\n`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the string contain actual newline characters, or does it contain ```\``` followed by `n`? Or ```\\``` followed by `n`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 ah it was `\\n` and so I was able to .replace() with a `\n` (and same swap for `\\t` for `\t`) and this solved it. Didn't appreciate that distinction, thank you!